# jQueryUI dialog won't go modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I need a modal dialog to open ontop of an tinyMCE editor and other jQuerified items. I followed the jquery site but its not modal, I can still change and access the rest of the page.

```
$('#sureDelete').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function(){
                            $('li#'+$id).remove();
                        },
                        "No":function(){
                        }
                    },
                    draggable: false
        });
<div id="dialogs">
```

`<div id="sureDelete">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</div>`
`</div>`
Also I don't have any styling added to the dialog. Can that be an issue?

Comment: @Theopile is that `dialog` code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` ?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation is this working in your browser?

Comment: Doug- its inside a $(function(){});
Reigel-yes that modal works im using chrome

Comment: The $(document),ready doesnt make a difference

Comment: How isn't in modal? Is the screen not grayed out or can you click on things? What are your other jQuerified items, if you remove them, does it work?

Comment: A silly question maybe, but do you reference the jQuery UI CSS?  If not then obviously the styles needed to make the dialog modal are not available.

Comment: @Marek, even if UI css is not there, it should still work... http://jsfiddle.net/M6HHV/

Comment: @Theopile - please take a look http://jsfiddle.net/hTMkF/ if that works... if that works, you have no problem in your UI dailog but in other things...

Comment: @Reigel - how exactly? .ui-widget-overlay has styles needed to position it over the entire screen - try disabling CSS on the jQuery UI demo and see if it still works

Comment: @Marek - on my first comment for you, i did include a link for your suggestion now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you include the jQueryUI base css file.
I.E.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="*jQueryUIDir*/css/*themeDir*/jquery-ui-*version*.custom.css"  type="text/css" />
```

Comment: really?... how come in this demo without the css, everything still works? http://jsfiddle.net/M6HHV/

Comment: Not sure. Could it be using the jquery ui core css?